# Converting text to int during a Join (casting?)

Tags: mysql, sql, casting

I have a query that looks like this:

```
SELECT p.prodname, p.prodcode, o.vovalue, p.productid, i.imageprodid, c.vcstock, p.prodcatids, t.catname
FROM isc_products p
LEFT OUTER JOIN isc_product_variation_combinations c ON c.vcproductid = p.productid
LEFT OUTER JOIN isc_product_variations v ON v.variationid = c.vcvariationid
LEFT OUTER JOIN isc_product_variation_options o ON o.voptionid = c.vcoptionids
LEFT OUTER JOIN isc_product_images i ON i.imageprodid = p.productid
LEFT OUTER JOIN isc_categories t ON t.categoryid = p.prodcatids
WHERE c.vcstock >1
AND  i.imageprodid IS NULL
ORDER BY ca.catname
```

I am trying to retrieve the category name (t.catname) in a column. 
It's returning a NULL value because of the Join of t.categoryid = p.prodcatids.

p.prodcatids is text (utf8_general) and t.categoryid is int(11).

How can I convert (cast?) p.prodcatids as int11 so that it will join on t.categoryid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if this is in mysql - did you check the convert and cast functions ? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast

Answer (score 3):

```
CAST(p.prodcatids AS UNSIGNED)
```

should do the job

Answer (score 2):

Just a couple of notes.

The fact that you can do a cast to get the desired result is no replacement for having a proper data structure.  You should have all foreign keys be the same type as the primary keys.  In particular, this wreaks havoc on the query optimizer, and generally guarantees a nested loop join (the least efficient kind).

Also, when you are presented with this situation, it is generally more accurate to convert away from the character data type.  This is because the cast function may not exactly match the other field.  For example "100" is not equal to "100.00".

However, this introduces the possibility of a failure in the cast.  Some databases, such as SQL Server, offer functions such as isnumeric and isdate to handle this situation.  Others do not.